# Custom background for activatedBackgroundIndicator on ActionBarSherlock doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, background, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I'm using **ActionBarSherlock** and I'm trying to customize the *activatedBackgroundIndicator* attribute for the row background.

If I use the latest android sdk, without the **ActionBarSherlock**, I'm able to customize the background creating the following style on *res/values/style.xml* and defining it on *AndroidManifest.xml* as *android:theme="@style/Theme.Custom"*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Custom" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then, my *res/drawable/activated_background.xml* contains the next code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
   <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/row_activated" />
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />  
</selector>
```

Finally, the code used to define each row in the ListView is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test_row"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sample_string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:padding="15dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result is shown on the screenshoot. Is a simple application with only a ListView with **ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE** and **getListView().setItemChecked(position, true)** when list item clicked.

The blue color of the standard selected row now is yellow and works perfectly.

[image: List without ABS]

The problem appears when I want to apply the same customization using the ActionBarSherlock.
Now The style file is the next and the background appears blue instead the custom yellow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Custom" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background</item>
        <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="activatedBackgroundIndicator">
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image: List with ABS]

I don't know if **ActionBarSherlock** supports the *android:activatedBackgroundIndicator* feature or if I forgot to implement something needed to be able to change the default color.

Any ideas?

Comment: ActionBarSherlock does support the activatedBackgroundIndicator attribute. Also, why do you have a style named "activatedBackgroundIndicator" defined in your XML?

Comment: I searched for projects implementing this functionality and I found  [Put.io](https://github.com/DSteve595/Put.io/blob/master/res/values/styles.xml) is using it.

Comment: I added the style trying to make it work, but if it isn't necessary I will delete it.  Then @Alex-Fu, the implementation using ActionBarSherlock must be the same as default?

Comment: Unless you will be referring to `activatedBackgroundIndicator` as a style, you don't need the style definition. Everything you have in your `Theme.Custom` definition is correct. What happens if you change `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` to `android:background="?attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` in your LinearLayout?

Comment: Also, you should include as many states as possible in your drawable selector. `android:state_activated="true"` isn't enough to cover all possibilities such as long press, click, focused, etc...

Comment: Thanks [@Alex-Fu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/993416/alex-fu) for your help. Finally I found the solution, that was change the context used in the adadpter.

Comment: @mlabraca your code is great, i'm a little confused about why set `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"`, if you set `<item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background</item>
  </style>` in your theme, why it does not apply to all list of activity automatically? i mean, is it just an option ? Unlike `android:editTextBackground` if you set, this will be applied automatically to all EditText in it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to the problem.
It was the **context** used in the row adapter. The constructor used is the shown in the following piece of code:

```
public RowAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> list) {
    this.mContext = activity.getApplicationContext();
    this.elements = list;
    this.theActivity = activity;

    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Just changing the **context** from:
`this.mContext = activity.getApplicationContext()`(Application-Context)
to
  `this.mContext = activity.getBaseContext()`(Activity-Context)
solved the problem and now the background is the custom one.

> Whenever you need to manipulate Views then go for **Activity-Context**, else **Application-Context** would be enough.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10347346/1211664) helped me to understand why to use *getBaseContext()* instead of *getApplicationContext()* in my case.

[image: custom row background]