# How to set custom color on selected/highlighted list-item in activatedBackgroundIndicator

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Hello I am developing an app using **ActionBarSherlock** and **Navigation Drawer**. I have created an initial navigation drawer with actionBar Sherlock just like this:

[image: activatedBackgroundIndicator]

Everything seems okay But I want to change default blue color of highlighted list-item with my custom color. I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344320/custom-background-for-activatedbackgroundindicator-on-actionbarsherlock-doesnt) but it is not working. What I need to do to achieve custom highlight color?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hello I have solved it for android OS version 11 and higher by applying style:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background</item>
</style>
```

activated_background in the drawable folder:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
   <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/uva_color" />
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/uva_color" />
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/uva_color" />
   <item android:drawable="@color/default_color" />  
</selector>
```

Color values in the values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="uva_color">#c31756</color>
    <color name="default_color">#111</color>
</resources>
```

And set choicemode in the listview:

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

And at last, send `getBaseContext()` to arrayApdater/your customAdapter as parameter instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

```
mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(this.getBaseContext(), title, icon);
```

Also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344320/custom-background-for-activatedbackgroundindicator-on-actionbarsherlock-doesnt) would help you.

Comment below if you face problem anywhere. I am ready to answer anytime, I don't want to let anyone getting trouble with this like me. Cheers!

Comment: Hi i am not able to get the highlight when a list view item is clicked.I mean the colour should stay for the clicked item when drawer is opened or closed