# How to disable ListView item after it has been clicked?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a simple array of `Strings` that I was displaying in a horizontal `ListView` with an `ArrayAdapter`. **What I'm looking to do is:** when the user selects an item from the `ListView`, make that item not clickable and change the background color of that item. Perhaps like a "grayed-out" look to it. I was looking into creating a custom `Adapter` and overriding the `isEnabled(int position)` method but I don't know how I would go about this. Any advice, suggestions, or help will be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: a custom list adapter sounds exactly what you need

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I was looking into creating a custom Adapter and overriding the `isEnabled(int position)` method but I don't know how I would go about this.

This is quite easy to do.  I recommend a SparseBooleanArray to track the enabled items for efficiency:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private SparseBooleanArray enabledItems = new SparseBooleanArray(); 

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return enabledItems.get(position, true);
    }

    public void toggleItem(int position) {
        boolean state = enabledItems.get(position, true);
        enabledItems.put(position, !state);
    }
}
```

The AutoComplete feature of Eclipse did must of the work, but here are some quick notes:

- You must override `areAllItemsEnabled()` along with `isEnabled()`
- I designed `toggle()` to be used by an `onItemClickListener()` you only need to call `adapter.toggle(position)`
- If you want to change the row's appearance (more than what enabling and disabling does by default) simply override `getView()`.  Don't forget to cover both cases:

  ```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

      if(!isEnabled(position)) { 
          /* change to disabled appearance */ 
      } 
      else { 
          /* restore default appearance */ 
      }
      return convertView;
  }
  ```

  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

pass position to adapter class when you click on list item

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        adapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
    }
```

add method of setSelectedIndex to adapter class

```
  public void setSelectedIndex(int ind)
    {
        selectedIndex = ind;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Now check the postion of this listview if same then enable and disable value in getView me method

```
 if(selectedIndex!= -1 && position == selectedIndex)
        {
            holder.tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.tv.setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
        }
        holder.tv.setText("" + (position + 1) + " " + testList.get(position).getTestText());
```

[Reference from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9281155/1339473)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setEnabled(bool)` property:

```
yourlistview.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Will this disable the entire ListView? Because I only need it to disable the clicked item within the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it will work or not

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
                // your code
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                view.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: This would work if each row was a separate View, but ListViews recycle rows for efficiency so this won't behave as you expect.