# Disabled click Item of ListView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-listview

I am using `SimpleAdapter` to bind `ListView`. Now, When User Clicks on Item, I want to disable that time from `Click()` event. I found some tutorial for `isEnabled()` but I am not understanding that how to use it ?
Please help me to solve this problem. I am using Custom `ListView`.

**This below code disables  `ListView`.**

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arrlist,
            R.layout.topicwisequestion, new String[] { "option" },
            new int[] { R.id.option }) {

        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            return ignoreDisabled;
        }

        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            if (areAllItemsEnabled()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    lvTWOptions.setAdapter(adapter);

    lvTWOptions.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              // Code...   
         }
    });
```

Comment: Just Comment onclick item,.. this is not that much clear can you send me your tutorial link. i will tell you answer..

Comment: @JeetenParmar, i did, Thank you for posting your answer. Happy coding.

Comment: @InnocentKiller, thank you. I hope it will help others.

Comment: Surely it gonna help other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this.

define a boolean variable

```
boolean ignoreDisabled = false;
```

Then in areAllItemsEnabled:

```
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return ignoreDisabled;
}
```

and then at the beginning of isEnabled:

```
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if (areAllItemsEnabled()) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

or else second way is define following code in your adapter class

```
private int mLastClicked;
public void setLastClicked(int lastClicked){
    mLastClicked = lastClicked;
}
```

and then

```
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    // return false if position == position you want to disable
}
```

add position of your last click event with isEnabled method.

For further reference you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885928/how-to-disable-listview-item-after-it-has-been-clicked)

Hope this is gonna help you.

Do it like this.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MyList, Layout, c,
new String[] { "Name", "Score" }, to)
{
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
{
return false;
}

public boolean isEnabled(int position)
{
return false;
}
};
```

Comment: Sorry mu mistake you have to add in your custom array adapter class

Comment: @GoRoS, yes i have taken this answer from another SO answer, but i am trying to solve the problem of this user.

Comment: @JeetenParmar, you just have to set both this method in your custom adapter class.

Comment: @JeetenParmar, Check the link which i have edited in my question.

Comment: boolean isEnabled(int position) is asking for return value, if i am using reference, it sets return ignoreDisabled; is it fine ? If i am doing this, then listview is disabled.

Comment: you have to set return true or false based on your operation you are doing.

Comment: But you are not checking item's position. You have to check first that which item is clicked in list-view, i think you have a variable pos or position in your onItemclick pass that position with isEnabled() position and then check

Comment: @JeetenParmar, Check my updated answer. Change name and score with your custom adapter.

Comment: @InnocentKiller, thank you... I used condition to check position and by which I have solved my problem. I have used only isEnabled().

Comment: Okay No problem. Glad it helped you, Can you just tell me which code is helped you. so i can post only that code next time if some one face same problem.

Comment: @InnocentKiller, check my posted answer. Vote up if u like it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to extend the simple adapter, maintain a list of indexes that have been clicked on, implement isEnabled(int) and check if the integer passed is in your list. You can then selectively disable list items after they've been clicked.

Adding some code:

```
public class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    private List<Integer> mDisabledRows;

    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        mDisabledRows = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public void disableRow(int index) {
        mDisableRows.clear();
        mDisabledRows.add(index);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int index) {
        return !mDisabledRows.contains(index);
    }
}
```

From your `onItemClick` method you would call `adapter.disableRow(position)`

I read that as you want to disable a row once it's clicked. If you only want to disable the last clicked row you could just store the last index clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I have used below code and solved my problem. It is very simple and easy. No need to use any extra codes.
What I have done is I have put condition to check position and then based on it, I disabled Clicked Item.

**My Code :**

```
    int pos;
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arrlist, R.layout.topicwisequestion, new String[] { "option" }, new int[] { R.id.option }) {

                public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                    if (position != 0) {
                        if (position == pos) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            };

            lvTWOptions.setAdapter(adapter);

            lvTWOptions.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    pos = position;
                }
            });
```