# Highlight a row in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am creating a listview with the reference from [this](http://www.debugrelease.com/2013/06/24/android-listview-tutorial-with-images-and-text/) link. Now am trying to highlight a particular row in listview. When am pressing the button the particular row got highlighted for a second. But what i want is that row should stay in same color until i presses the button in next row. my listview is

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainListView"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layer_list"
        android:dividerHeight="2px"
        >
```

and in listview am placing a textview and an imageview. For highlighting the view i followed [this](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/tag/clickable/.) tutorial.  Am new to android. Help me in achieving this. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Create a selector for the Cells

Comment: retain the position of the item which is selected and use it accordingly in getView - possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281000/android-keep-listviews-item-highlighted-once-one-has-been-clicked

Comment: @user try my answer it will work definitely.I have two implemented this functionality

Comment: I tried in creating selector. But it didn't worked for me. Can u explain in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create A Selector in the **Draw-able Folder** listview_item_selection_effect.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
    <item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#00a7eb" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

In Your Layout which has the **ListView**

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

In Your **Activity** On ListView item Clicked

```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3){ 
       listView.setSelector(R.drawable.listview_item_selection_effect);
    listView.setItemChecked(position,true);
    }
});
```

In the **ListView**

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

Comment: Position is the Item that is selected in the listview

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i don't want to mention the position previously means on runtime when am pressing the up button listview should highlight the particular row until i press the next one.

Comment: what is the problem your are now facing,this is working perfectly for me if u can send me u r sample project i can resolve this issue

Comment: If am putting choicemode in listview it is not working friend. But without that it is working perfectly.. Thank u friend :-) ..

Answer (score 0):

a)  Use a custom layout

```
    MyLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
    boolean check = false
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
          if (checked){
             //HIGHLIGHT THE BACKGROUND
          }{
            // remove the background
          }

    }
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!check);
    }
    }
```

b )In custom listview item use `MyLayout` as layout

c )In your activity implement `OnItemClickListener` and in `onItemClick` 
         call `listview.setItemChecked(position, true);`