# How can I change default background color of a selected ListView item in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I want to change the default color (blue) of a selected item in a Navigation Drawer in Android.  I have gotten it to work in past projects, but I cannot in the project I am currently working on.

This is the app theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>
</style>
```

This is the activated_background drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selected"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selected"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selected"/>
</selector>
```

Finally, this is the navigation drawer fragment.

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:background="#cccc"
tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

Like I said, this has worked for me before.  The only difference between projects that I can think of is that before, my app theme was inherited from "Theme.AppCompat" and this project's theme is inherited from "android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar".  Also, I am using v4 support fragments in my new project, while as in the other project I was just using the standard fragment.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Instead of using my theme to try and apply the style, I just created my own xml layout for the list items instead of using the default and set the selector from there.

Here is what the list item xml looks like.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/text1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
  android:textColor="@drawable/list_txtcolor"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:paddingStart="?android:listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
  android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
  android:background="@drawable/activated_background"
  android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall">
</TextView>
```

As you can see, I just set the item background to my selector.

```
android:background="@drawable/activated_background"
```

And again, here is my selector.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selected"/>
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selected"/>
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selected"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit:

Seems like the question is how to *keep* an item in a `ListView` selected, not actually how to set the resulting background of a selected item.

See this great answer for how change the background of a `ListView` item once it is selected:

[Android - Keep ListView's item highlighted once one has been clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281000/android-keep-listviews-item-highlighted-once-one-has-been-clicked)

The basic idea is that when the item is tapped, you change it's background (or whatever else). The tricky part is you must have your List adapter *remember* the row that is selected. Otherwise when/if you scroll the list/navigation drawer, you'll lose the selection.

#### Original Answer:

You need to set a custom `ListView` style in `AppTheme` in which you set the `android:listSelector` item to `@drawable/activated_background`.

If you don't want that style for your entire app, just specify that style for the `ListView` in your application drawer layout, or even more simply just set the `android:listSelector` property of that `ListView` and don't even bother defining a style.

Comment: I have already tried this.  This only changes the color when the list item is pressed.  After being pressed, it goes back to blue.

Comment: Do you mean you're looking to indicate which item is currently selected, as long as it's respective activity/fragment/etc is shown?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: updating answer..one sec.

Comment: I figured it out.  I added my answer.  Thanks for the help, though!  It was much simpler than I had expected.