# Select an item in a ListFragment by default

Tags: android

I hava a problem with my code. I want to select the first element in a ListFragment by default (when the Activity is visible by the first time, I want the first element to be selected) but I am not able to do that. This is my code:

In ListFragment (onActivityCreated):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.fragment_selector, ActivityMain2.mTitleArray);
setListAdapter(adapter);
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setSelector(R.drawable.fragment_listselector);      
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
listView.setItemChecked(1, true);
listView.setSelection(1);
listView.setSelected(true);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

layout/fragment_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="5dp"
  android:textSize="32sp" >

</TextView>
```

drawable/fragment_listselector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:drawable="@color/default_color" android:state_selected="false"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/pressed_color" android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

Any help? Thank you

Comment: Do you want to "keep it selected", visible with background-color?

Comment: Yes, that´s it. I want the background color indicate the selection

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Keep ListView's item highlighted once one has been clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281000/android-keep-listviews-item-highlighted-once-one-has-been-clicked)

Comment: No, that is working. I want to select or keep selected the first item when I open the Activity and I don´t touch the screen...

Answer (score 1):

So your Question is a duplicate of [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281000/android-keep-listviews-item-highlighted-once-one-has-been-clicked)

ListView doesn't keep items selected, so the custom selector does not work!
You have to write your own Adapter and remember the selected Item with a field, as the answer states.

Then just call `listView.setSelection(0)` in `onCreate` and you are fine.

I have used the code from there myself and it works fine.

Comment: But when you open the Activity for the first time, is there any item selected?

Comment: Nope, you can implement your Adapter that it shows your first Item as selected; or just call `listView.setSelection(0)`

Comment: I edited my adapter to higlight the first Item: `if (selectedIndex != -1 && position == selectedIndex || (selectedIndex == -1 && position == 0))`

You are welcome.