# Android Listview - scrolling removes highlight from row

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I have a ListView with 10 Items. So when I click on the first Item and scroll to the end, the highlight of the first Item removed.

Some code:

my ListView

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        >
</ListView>
```

simplerow

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:focusable="false"
android:background="@drawable/selecter"
>
```

selecter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gray">
</item>

<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/blue" >
    </item>
</selector>
```

Activity

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    view.setSelected(true);
    ...
```

Comment: Show more code. The code you showed is fine. The bug must originate from somewhere else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Keep ListView's item highlighted once one has been clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281000/android-keep-listviews-item-highlighted-once-one-has-been-clicked)

Comment: You should wrap up with some global list of booleans,say 'isSelected', of same size as that of listview's number of rows, and set corresponding index true if that row is selected. Now, in getView, if(isSelected(position)), then only view.setSelected(true), else view.setSelected(false).

Comment: When you scroll , your views are rendered again . you must keep selected state in somewhere relative to position  or id and in  getView method of your list adapter ,  you must set selected true or false acccording to position or id