# ListView inside DrawerLayout loses selected state when closed

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, xamarin.android

I have a drawer layout inside it I have ListView with custom selector that gives the selected item some color. when drawerlayout is open, clicking any items changes its color based on selector but after closing the drawerlayout somehow the selected list item loses its state. All list items is getting default state. How can I keep state for listitem in listview after closing drawerlayout?

Comment: ListView has a [setSelection()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)) method.  You could try that.

Comment: Yes I can set selection but after closing drawer all selections are cleared

Comment: Is your `ListView` like the `app:menu` of `NavigationView`? Why don't you use menu? In case I misunderstand your question, could you please show your layout? Also, as for your question itself, you can refer to this case: [Android - Keep ListView's item highlighted once one has been clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281000/android-keep-listviews-item-highlighted-once-one-has-been-clicked).